# If meal continued into the night what do I say in benching

Tags: halacha, bentching, meal-seudah

1. started eating before (shekiya) night, Rosh Chodesh came with the night
2. started on Rosh Chodesh and the next day is not Rosh Chodesh
3. started on Shabos/yomtov and the next day is not Shabos/yomtov (if did or did not Davin maariv)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the rule is: "If you eat kezais in kodesh you add special bench"

Therefore, in all those cases you have to add Rtzei/Yaale Veyavo.

---

*After searching for sources*

[Here](http://etzion.vbm-torah.org/vbm/archive/5-halak/hamazon.rtf) is a booklet of R. Yosef Zvi Rimon.
The paragraph that starts with the words "יעלה ויבוא בסעודת ר"ח שנמשכה לערב"
gives lot of useful references on the topic. (I can't say for sure which page it is, since this is an rtf document, so it depend with what reader you open it).

The outline is:

> אם התחיל לאכול לפני ראש-חודש ונמשכה סעודתו לתוך ראש חודש (ואכל פת גם בלילה), או אם התחיל לאכול בראש-חודש ונתעכב בברכת המזון עד מוצאי ראש-חודש - מזכיר יעלה ויבוא.
>
> If one started to eat before Rosh Hodesh and continued his meal into Rosh Hodesh (and also eat at the night), or if he started to eat in Roch Hodesh and delayed his bench till after Rosh Hodesh - he recites Yaale Veyavo

Answer (score 1):

as @jutky said

"in all those cases you have to add Rtzei/Yaale Veyavo."

it seems from the Shulchan aruch harav bellow that the general rules are

as @Scimonster said we "follow the beginning of the meal", if he did not daven maariv (even before night) or make havdolo or say "(boruch) hamavdil ben kodesh lchol"

and as @jutky said "If you eat kezais in kodesh you add special bench" even if you started the meal on the previous day

[Shulchan aruch harav 188.17](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/17/188/17)

rough partial translation

if he was eating on shabbos and the meal continued into the night even a few hours he recites about shabos in the birchas hamozoin. **because everything goes with the beginning of the meal**, then is the time when the obligation to recite (about the day) started... and the day leaving dose not change it. same by rosh chodesh (yaale vyavo), hanuka, and purim (al hanisim)...

if the meal of erev shabos or yomtov went into the night you need to recite about shabos or rosh chodesh if you ate a kizayes after it got dark. even though he was exempt when the meal started since the **obligation came on you by your eating the kizayes when it got dark**, same law by channuka and purim ...

this was if he did not daven maariv. but if he davened maariv even when it was still day he dose not recite about the day even if he is benching while it is still day

and needless to say that if the meal continued until saturday night and then he davened maariv he dose not recite about shabos in the birchas hamozoin, even though that we go according the the beginning of the meal... it will look like his words are contradicting themselves that he prays the payer (maariv) of the next day and then recites about the previous day (any way if he did not daven maariv and Saturday night is rosh chodesh he should recite about shabos and also about rosh chodesh if he ate a kesais after it got dark and their is no contradiction (in his words) here since he recites about shabos first and after that about rosh chodesh, even though we cant say that he is excepting rosh chodesh now when he is reciting after he recited about shabos, since it is (rosh chodesh) exepted when the sun set   ...)
...
if after it go dark he did not eat a kezaies of bread ... he only recites about shabos as long as he did not yet daven maariv.

if he made havdoro on the table (an a cup) the law is the same as if he davend maariv he dose not recite shabos in the birchat hamazon

if he only said "(boruch) hamavdil ben kodesh lchol" without a cup ... better not to do anything (not to recite about the previous day )...

קפח נוסח ברכה ג' ודיני ברכת המזון בשבת והטועה בברכת המזון ובו י"ז סעיפים:

יז היה אוכל בשבת ונמשכה סעודתו עד שחשיכה אפילו כמה שעות בלילה מזכיר של שבת בברכת המזון לפי **שהכל הולך אחר התחלת הסעודה** שאז חל עליו חיוב הזכרה מעין המאורע ולא נפקע ממנו חיוב זה ביציאת היום. וה"ה לראש חודש חנוכה ופורים ויש אומרים שבראש חודש חנוכה ופורים הואיל ואין בהם תוספת מחול על הקדש אינו מזכיר מעין המאורע אחר שיצא היום ואין נוהגין כן.

ומכל מקום אם נמשכה סעודתו בערב שבת או בערב ראש חודש תוך הלילה צריך להזכיר של שבת או של ראש חודש אם אכל כזית משחשיכה אע"פ שבתחלת הסעודה היה פטור מלהזכיר לפי שמכל מקום **חל עליו חיוב ההזכרה באכילת כזית שמשחשיכה** וה"ה לחנוכה ופורים. ויש אומרים שאפילו לא אכל כזית משחשיכה צריך להזכיר כיון שבשעה שמברך כבר קידש היום של שבת או יום טוב או ראש חודש חנוכה ופורים. וכן אם נמשכה סעודתו בשבת או ראש חודש חנוכה ופורים עד הלילה אע"פ שגמרה מבעוד יום אלא שמברך בלילה אינו מזכיר מעין המאורע (של אותו היום) כיון שכבר פנה היום ונוהגין כסברא הראשונה.

והוא שלא התפלל ערבית אע"פ שהציבור התפללו כבר אבל אם התפלל ערבית אפילו מבעוד יום באמצע סעודתו שוב אינו מזכיר מעין המאורע של אותו היום אפילו מברך ג"כ מבעוד יום ואצ"ל מי שנמשכה סעודתו למוצאי שבת והתפלל ערבית שאינו מזכיר עוד של שבת בברכת המזון ואע"פ שלסברא ראשונה שהכל הולך אחר התחלת סעודה היה ראוי להזכיר גם אחר תפלת ערבית מכל מקום יהא נראה שדבריו סותרים זה את זה שתחלה התפלל תפלת יום שלאחריו ואח"כ מזכיר יום העבר. (מכל מקום אם לא התפלל ערבית ומוצאי שבת הוא ראש חודש מזכיר של שבת וגם של ראש חודש אם אכל כזית משחשיכה ואין כאן סתירה כיון שמזכיר של שבת תחלה ואח"כ של ראש חודש ואע"פ שאי אפשר לומר שמקבל עליו ראש חודש עכשיו כשמזכירו אחר שהזכיר כבר שבת שהרי מקובל ועומד היא מששקעה החמה וגם אם היה מקבלו עכשיו לא חל עליו חיוב ההזכרה עכשיו אלא כשאכל כבר קודם שהזכיר של שבת אין לחוש לכל זה שאף שחל עליו ראש חודש כבר מזכיר הוא של שבת כמו שמזכיר מעין המאורע בכל מוצאי שבת ומוצאי ראש חודש אפילו כמה שעות בלילה שכבר חלף והלך לו יום שמזכיר הואיל והתחלת הסעודה היתה בו ואע"פ שנראה לכל העולם שהוא לילה אין זו סתירה כל שהוא לא עשה כבר דבר הסותר לזה וה"ה במוצאי שבת לראש חודש כשמזכיר של שבת לא עשה עדיין דבר הסותר לזה ואח"כ כשמזכיר של ראש חודש האמת הוא שהוא מזכיר). ויש אומרים שאעפ"כ זו סתירה היא ולכן מזכיר של ראש חודש שהיא חובה לדברי הכל ולא של שבת שהיא מחלוקת אבל במוצאי שבת של חנוכה ופורים מזכיר של שבת ולא של חנוכה ופורים לפי שכל יום שאין בו קרבן מוסף אין הזכרתו חובה בברכת המזון כמ"ש סי' תרפ"ב (עיין לעיל סי"[ד]) ותרצ"ה והעיקר כסברא הראשונה.

ואם משחשיכה לא אכל כזית פת לדברי הכל מזכיר שבת לבד כל שלא התפלל ערבית.

ואם הבדיל על שולחנו דינו כהתפלל ערבית ושוב אינו מזכיר של שבת בברכת המזון

ואם אמר המבדיל בין קודש לחול בלבד בלא כוס כמ"ש בסי' רצ"ט יש להסתפק (ולפי מ"ש כאן אין כאן ספק דלא גרע מהזכרת ראש חודש) אם דינו כהתפלל ערבית ולפיכך שב ואל תעשה עדיף שהרי יש אומרים שלעולם אינו מזכיר של שבת אחר שיצא היום:

Answer (score 0):

What i was told to do in such a case is to follow the beginning of the meal. So, for your cases:

1. No Ya'aleh Veyavoh
2. Yes Ya'aleh Veyavoh
3. Yes R'tzei / Ya'aleh Veyavoh.

I'll try and look up the source for this later.